# How to write complex sql queries in properties file for java jdbc application

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

My requirement is to make the sql queries external to my java code so that it can me modified by manual testers. I need some suggestion/help to write the properties file for my utility class. I know how use/load properties file. But I need some idea about about complex sql queries which can be used by my jdbc classes, when the queries modified in future it should have less impact/ no impact on my java code.

In my properties file which is in my classpath

```
query1=select org_id from organization where PRIMARY-KEY=454545452
query2=select * from organization_address where org_id in
```

and in my java class

```
String query1 = Queries.getQuery("query1");
String query2 = Queries.getQuery("query2");
String finalQuery = query2+"("+query1+")";
```

I need more flexibility either in properties file or in my java class.

Comment: Is Queries your custom class to read query from properties file?

Comment: yes, it is reading the properties file from my classpath

Comment: You might want to look at MyBatis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could proceed like this:

this could be your generic select query on basis of primary key

```
query1=select {0} from {1} where {2} = {3}
```

Then can at the time of retrieving query you can use like this

```
 property = MessageFormat.format(query1,new String[]{"org_id","organization","PRIMARY-KEY","454545452"});
```

Similarly you can generalize the queries and set the values in your java code.
It depends on you what level of generalization you want.

Comment: can you please elaborate a little about the code. I think query1 is in properties file and the second line is in java class. What is MessageFormat???. I think you are still hardcoding the column and table in java class which I don't prefer. Is there any way to proceed with same approach but reading the column as well as the table name properties file.

Comment: MessageFormat is a java class the code above you see.. I have placed property placeholders and in java using MessageFormat I am passing the query and an array of values that are to be substituted  in place of property placeholders, so {0} will be substituted with "org_id" and similarly other values.
If you donot want to code tablename and column name in java then you need to have separate property queries for every table in property file. You can proceed like that too, but the primary key will be available at run time I guess so use placeholder for primary key

Comment: Ok, I have few doubt: can I directly use property as sql statement??? Also I need a sample property file snipped what you suggested. I can load the property file using `InputStream is = 
      Queries.class.getResourceAsStream(propFileName); ... props.load(is);` am I right!!!

Comment: You can use anything according to your requirement.
paste the above property above in a property file and you will have your snippet.
Yes you are right.